# I have this version of Qt. still unable to use Qt.controls and QtQuick 2.0.

Tags: qt, qt-quick, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I have updated my Qt version to

- Qt Creator 2.7.1
- Based on Qt 5.0.2 (32 bit)
- Built on Sep 6 2013 at 08:23:22

Still I am not able to use Qt Quick controls and Qt Quick 2.0. I get this error

```
module "QtQuick" version 2.0 is not installed
import QtQuick 2.0
```

I have imported QtQuick 2.0 still it's not working.

Comment: Whoch operation system are you using? From which source did you install Qt?

Comment: @SimonWarta OS is Ubuntu 13.10. Installed Qt by downloading from  <http://qt-project.org/downloads>. Downloaded version:- qt-linux-opensource-5.2.0-x86-offline.run. Please let me know if you need additional info.

Answer (score 0):

The solution might be adding:

```
QT += quick
```

in your .pro file. If it doesn't help please install [this](http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/create/get-the-sdk/).

Comment: I am actually working on QML file and there is no .pro file in that. All I have is one .qmlproject file.